# Test kinect:No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My environment is Ubuntu12.04, ros indigo. "http://learn.turtlebot.com" was followed by me, but when i run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

the logs of terminal show

```
[ INFO] [1463638647.225005146]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

It hits me with long time, help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235440/test-kinect:no-devices-connected....-waiting-for-devices-to-be-connected/) by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`openni_kinect` is deprecated, you should use freenect_stack instead from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_stack)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-stack
```

And make sure the Kinect is connected, and if you are using Kinect V2, it should be connected to Intel USB3.0 port.

Once you install it, you need to start publishing the kinect camera topics by running the freenect_launch file:

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

Then open another shell to visualize the rgb image or any other topic:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2016-05-28**:
Yes and if that doesn't work then make sure the Kinect is getting 12v of power. Pretty obvious but it happens to the best of us hehe

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-05-28**:
I follow your approach, but the problem still appear.Could you give me a way which include all step for connect kinect2?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-29**:
The kinect seems working!
I just edited my answer, check it out

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2016-05-29**:
Is this with Kinect v2?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-29**:
Should works for both.
freenect_launch seems already working!

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2016-05-29**:
Should? Have you tested with both?

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-05-29**:
@ROSkinect, Yes, freenect_launch already working. But no devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected. I'm sure that i connect Kinect2 with my computer, typing lsusb, 3 Microsoft Corp had arised.